# How to monkeypatch function with requests and ZipFile?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, monkeypatching

I would like to monkeypatch the following function using pytest because I want to provide my own local test file.

```
def iterate_urls(dl_urls: list, path: str):
    request = None
    for url in dl_urls:
        try:
            request = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            exit('Error: URLs are invalid. URL format might have been changed or website might have moved. ' + str(err))

        zipped_data = ZipFile(BytesIO(request.content))
        zipped_data.extractall(path)
```

I already tried the following:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patched_env(monkeypatch):
    class GetMockReturn:
        content = bytes()

    monkeypatch.setenv('DATABASE', 'test_update.db')
    monkeypatch.setattr(dp.requests, 'get', lambda *_, **__: GetMockReturn)
    monkeypatch.setattr(dp, 'ZipFile', lambda *_, **__: None)
    reload(sr)
```

The dp module is imported and contains the iterate_urls() function, which needs to be patched, whereas the sr module is the module to be tested here

My problem is that ZipFile would not except anything else than a real Zip file and I cannot get it patched.

Does anyone know how to get around that?

Comment: Do you need to patch `ZipFile`? Why not just return local file contents in `GetMockReturn`? `class GetMockReturn: contents = Path('myfile.zip').read_bytes()`

Comment: @hoefling I would like to avoid creating a local zip file. The test file I have saved locally is not zipped.

Comment: Then it's unclear what the local file represents, the contents of the zip file? You can of course make `ZipFile` a no-op by replacing it with a `unittest.mock.MagicMock`.

Comment: The real purpose of the download function is to download a zip file from a server and extract its contents to a specified path. However, I have a local test file which does not have to be unzipped anymore. So I just want to ignore the complete download and unzip functionality. I'll try MagicMock. I hoped there was a possibility not using unittest.

Comment: You can also subclass `ZipFile`, overriding a selection methods with your own no-op impls and use it for patching.